# What's the diffrence bettwen timezone.now and auto_now_add parameters in DateTimeField field in Django models?

Tags: django, django-models, timezone

I'm writing my first Django app - blog. When creating Post model I'm asked to create publish and created fields with timezone import.

```
publish = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

It's explained that "By using auto_now_add, the date will be saved automatically when creating an object" and "timezone.now returns the current datetime in a timezone-aware format".

So it seems to me that they both same job. Why not use default=timezone.now in both fields? What's the difference?
It's  my first question so  sorry in advance if I made some mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

They are the same, except for one thing: `auto_now_add=True` overrides any initial value you pass when creating the object, whereas `default=timezone.now` will allow you to set your own, different value.

You can read it in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add)

Answer (score 0):

The `auto_now_add` will set the `timezone.now()` only when the instance is created, and `auto_now` will update the field every time the save method is called.

`default=timezone.now` means setting the default current time when you add or modify a field for a model that already exists, since there can be records in the database, and you need to specify what to fill in for these existing records.
Thanks!